# Execute Groovy script after SOAP request in SoapUI

Tags: soap, groovy, soapui

I execute a script from a `Groovy` script in `SoapUI` project.

```
def tCase = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.testCases["TC1"]
def tStep = tCase.testSteps["attachIt"]
tStep.run(testRunner, context)
```

There is another loop in this script, which is to execute a `SOAP` request. After that two more `Groovy` scripts should be executed to process output. These are in same testcase after `SOAP` request step, but aren't executed automatically.

Comment: Can you please show the screen shot of the `TC1`?

Comment: @Rao : There are a properties, and SOAP requests, Groovy scripts mixed in this testcase.

Comment: And you want to run what steps? Screen will still help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets Assume you have a testcase which has 5 steps

As per my understanding you are trying to execute few steps(say Step1,step2) of the testcase via a groovy(step 3) and you are expecting that step4 and step5 should execute automatically.

**That will not happen**

So you can disable step 1 & step 2

So now what will happen when you run the **test case**(not step) system will execute step 1 & step2 via step3 and once step 3 is done step4 & step5 will run automatically.(since you ran the test case_

In case you like that step4 & step5 should execute automatically you can use the same code as you have shared and use groovy script teststep names in it and disable those steps